# luajit2.0.0 -- Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: lua, luajit

I use a simple example from http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleLuaApiExample to make a test. The sample can be statically linked with libluajit.a with a success, but this error message occurs when you run it:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I use LuaJIT-2.0.0 released at 2012-11-08. My OS is Mac OSX Lion 10.7.5.

```
$ uname -a
Darwin macmatoMacBook-Pro.local 11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

The test steps:

#### compile luajit-2.0.0

```
$ cd lj2
$ ls
COPYRIGHT Makefile  README    doc       dynasm    etc       src
$ make
==== Building LuaJIT 2.0.0 ====
make -C src
DYNLINK   libluajit.so
LINK      luajit
OK        Successfully built LuaJIT
==== Successfully built LuaJIT 2.0.0 ====
$ rm src/*.so            # force to use the static version: libluajit.a
$ cd ..
```

#### compile and run the sample app

Both **test.c** and **script.lua** come from [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleLuaApiExample). The folder **lj2** contains the source code of the above luajit-2.0.0, just compiled successfully.

```
$ ls
lj2 script.lua test.c
```

use clang compiler

```
$ clang -o test test.c -I./lj2/src -L./lj2/src -lluajit
$ ./test
Segmentation fault: 11
```

use gcc compiler

```
$ gcc -o test test.c -I./lj2/src -L./lj2/src -lluajit
$ ./test 
Segmentation fault: 11
```

---

But if I replace lj2/src/luajit.c with test.c, it will give me a success. This is very strange. See below:

```
$ cd lj2
$ make clean
$ mv src/luajit.c src/luajit.c.orig 
$ cp ../test.c src/luajit.c
$ make
$ cp src/luajit ../
$ cd ..
$ ./luajit
The table the script received has:
1   2
2   4
3   6
4   8
5   10
Returning data back to C
Script returned: 30
```

Comment: You should probably be doing `sudo make install` as part of the build of luajit.  Also why do you want to link it statically?

Comment: @finnw I want to embed luajit in my app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem resolved. There is an section which explains how to Embedding LuaJIT in this page:
http://luajit.org/install.html

> - If you're building a 64 bit application on OSX which links directly or indirectly against > LuaJIT, you need to link your main executable with these flags:
>
>   -pagezero_size 10000 -image_base 100000000
>
> Also, it's recommended to rebase all (self-compiled) shared libraries which are loaded at  runtime on OSX/x64 (e.g. C extension modules for Lua). See: man rebase

Now, let me test it again:

```
$ clang -o test test.c -O3 -I./lj2/src -L./lj2/src -lluajit -pagezero_size 10000 -image_base 100000000
$ ./test 
The table the script received has:
1   2
2   4
3   6
4   8
5   10
Returning data back to C
Script returned: 30
```

And valgrind returns

```
$ valgrind ./test
bad executable (__PAGEZERO is not 4 GB)
valgrind: ./test: cannot execute binary file
```

That's another question.